# Error executing DDL "alter table compte add constraint FK2hw4shqsxc782lychpkr52lmv foreign key

Tags: spring-boot

Hello i don't know what happened there

```
org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL "alter table compte add constraint FK2hw4shqsxc782lychpkr52lmv foreign key (code_cli) references client (code_client)" via JDBC Statement
    [...]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Can't create table `banque`.`compte` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")
[...]

2020-06-26 19:19:45.036  WARN 15232 --- [         task-1] o.h.t.s.i.ExceptionHandlerLoggedImpl     : GenerationTarget encountered exception accepting command : Error executing DDL "alter table compte add constraint FKbm21kemcgkptyq3x0ge8ciaqu foreign key (code_emp) references employe (code_employe)" via JDBC Statement

org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL "alter table compte add constraint FKbm21kemcgkptyq3x0ge8ciaqu foreign key (code_emp) references employe (code_employe)" via JDBC Statement
[...]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Can't create table `banque`.`compte` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")
[...]

2020-06-26 19:19:45.238  WARN 15232 --- [         task-1] o.h.t.s.i.ExceptionHandlerLoggedImpl     : GenerationTarget encountered exception accepting command : Error executing DDL "alter table operation add constraint FKkr9nfjf0ipqrw5xwcf9jqq6gv foreign key (code_cpte) references compte (code_compte)" via JDBC Statement

org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL "alter table operation add constraint FKkr9nfjf0ipqrw5xwcf9jqq6gv foreign key (code_cpte) references compte (code_compte)" via JDBC Statement
    [...]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Duplicate key name 'FKkr9nfjf0ipqrw5xwcf9jqq6gv'
```

The messages:

> Error executing DDL "alter table compte add constraint
> FK2hw4shqsxc782lychpkr52lmv foreign key (code_cli) references client
> (code_client)" via JDBC Statement
>
> Can't create table `banque`.`compte` (errno: 150 "Foreign key
> constraint is incorrectly formed")
>
> Error executing DDL "alter table compte add constraint
> FKbm21kemcgkptyq3x0ge8ciaqu foreign key (code_emp) references employe
> (code_employe)" via JDBC Statement
>
> Error executing DDL "alter table compte add constraint
> FKbm21kemcgkptyq3x0ge8ciaqu foreign key (code_emp) references employe
> (code_employe)" via JDBC Statement
>
> Can't create table `banque`.`compte` (errno: 150 "Foreign key
> constraint is incorrectly formed")
>
> Error executing DDL "alter table operation add constraint
> FKkr9nfjf0ipqrw5xwcf9jqq6gv foreign key (code_cpte) references compte
> (code_compte)" via JDBC Statement
>
> Error executing DDL "alter table operation add constraint
> FKkr9nfjf0ipqrw5xwcf9jqq6gv foreign key (code_cpte) references compte
> (code_compte)" via JDBC Statement
>
> Duplicate key name 'FKkr9nfjf0ipqrw5xwcf9jqq6gv'

Comment: Can you please add more information about what you are doing, what you are expecting and when this exception happens

Comment: Please read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask  Just posting a 5 page wall of an unformatted stack-trace is **not a question**. The more work you make your readers do, the less likely you are to get a helpful answer.

Comment: Please tell us 1. How do you create the schema? Do you have a property `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update` and what's the value? (update/create/create-drop...). 2. Does the DB schema exist already or are you creating it completely from scratch? 3. How does the Entity look like? Do you provide any custom SQL snippets for schema generation?